# laravel ошибка при форматировании формата created_at

Tags: laravel

Добрый день пытаюсь поменять формат поля created_at при выводе во view,  но выдает ошибку Call to a member function format() on string

```
 <td>{{$item->created_at->format('d.m.Y')}}</td>
```

Comment: посмотри ответ вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533377/laravel-error-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-string) или [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020692/call-to-a-member-function-format-on-string-in-laravel)

Comment: Спасибо, нашел решение